# .net and classic asp

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

I have classic asp and as well as aspx files in my project. The project uses both types of files for certain functionality. but the problem is pipeline mode of iis 7. it is set to classic.

when I execute the aspx page within the classic asp website, parser error message appears saying "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Under IIS , it should be aaded as application and not virtual directory. Also, Create new app pool for this site and set managed pipeline to integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Your error "This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS." says all.
You have set up your application as Virtual directory and not application in IIS. Convert virtual directory to application by right clicking virtual directory and selecting option "Convert to Application"

Comment: it is set as an application only.